# How to make radio button in multiple row in one column

Tags: android

I create 10 radio button in one column but I don't know how to make them into one radio group, because in my layout. I have column and layout_span.

For example in the first column 1 (Usefulness). I want make radio button in one group but if I put another radio button under Good(6-7), it should make another radio group.

```
<TableRow android:background="#f2a344">
            <TextView
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:text="CSP650-PROJECT EXHIBIT AWARD EVALUATION (F11) RUBRIC"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:background="#fadc1f">
            <TextView android:lines="1"
                android:text="Assessment Criteria" />
            <TextView android:text="Excellent(8-10)"/>
            <TextView android:text="Good(6-7)"/>
            <TextView android:text="Satisfactory(5)"/>
            <TextView android:text="Poor(1-4)"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:background="#cb7ded">
            <TextView
                android:text="1. Usefulness"

                android:lines="6"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="1">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:id="@+id/radio213" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="9"
                        android:id="@+id/radio214"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="8"
                        android:id="@+id/radio215"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Very useful and innovative."
                    android:id="@+id/textView137" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="1">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7"
                        android:id="@+id/radio216"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="6"
                        android:id="@+id/radio217"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Useful and show some \n innovative potential."
                    android:id="@+id/textView138" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="1">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:id="@+id/radio218"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Somewhat useful but \n lack innovation."
                    android:id="@+id/textView139" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="1">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="4"
                        android:id="@+id/radio219"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:id="@+id/radio220"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:id="@+id/radio221"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:id="@+id/radio222"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-Lack usefulness"
                    android:id="@+id/textView140" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Radio Group orientation to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot or some UI of how should your UI look like exactly. That'll of help in understanding the problem exactly

Comment: radio button under (good 6-7) in another radio group .. i want make all radio button in layout 1. Usefulness from Excellent until poor in one radio group .

Answer (score 0):

U can use this type format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TableRow>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"></View>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#eee"></View>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2">
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#eee"></View>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"></View>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#bbb"></View>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: u can put your radio button inside <TableRow> it means

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by java code

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
RadioButton rb1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
RadioButton rb2 = findViewById(R.id.rb2);
RadioButton rb3 = findViewById(R.id.rb3);
RadioButton rb4 = findViewById(R.id.rb4);
rg.addView(rb1);
rg.addView(rb2);
rg.addView(rb3);
rg.addView(rb4);
```